# Tricky issue. Inserting json data

Tags: php, mysql, json

My json:

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "number": 10,
      "line_items": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "sub": "21.00",
          "sub_tax": "0.00",
          "total": "21.00",
          "total_tax": "0.00",
          "quantity": 1,
          "tax_class": null,
          "meta": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

what I have at the moment:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents(JSON_URL), true);
foreach ($json as $u => $z){
    foreach ($z as $n => $line){
$number = $line['number'];
$line_item_id = $line['line_items'][0]['id'];
            $line_item_sub = $line['line_items'][0]['sub];
            $line_item_sub_tax = $line['line_items'][0]['sub_tax'];
            $line_item_total = $line['line_items'][0]['total'];
            $line_item_total_tax = $line['line_items'][0]['total_tax'];
            $line_item_quantity = $line['line_items'][0]['quantity'];
            $line_item_tax_class = $line['line_items'][0]['tax_class'];

}
}
```

End of the foreach I insert those datas in the database. The problem here is following:

If there is more than one line_items, it should make new row in the database. Inserting only: `number` and the additional `line_items`.

Keep in mind that there could be, lets say 20 different database rows created where is only one `line_items`, but only two of those have more than one `line_item` array. How could I make this work?

I have tried something like this:

```
$countid = $line['line_items'][0]['id'];
        if(count($countid) > 1){
            $number = $line['order_number'];
            $line_item_id = $line['line_items'][0]['id'];
            $line_item_sub = $line['line_items'][0]['sub'];
            $line_item_sub_tax = $line['line_items'][0]['sub_tax'];
            $line_item_total = $line['line_items'][0]['total'];
            $line_item_total_tax = $line['line_items'][0]['total_tax'];
            $line_item_quantity = $line['line_items'][0]['quantity'];
            $line_item_tax_class = $line['line_items'][0]['tax_class'];
        } else {
<!-- Insert data normally -->
```

But I don't think so that this could work. Do you have any ideas how I could make this right?
Let me know if I can provide more information. Thank you!

How I'm inserting the datas:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("111.11.111.11","username","password","database") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

// prepare your insert query
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO table_name( values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names, values_names,) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

// bind the upcoming variable names to the query statement
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'isssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss', $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables $values_variables);
```

foreach loops grab about 45 different items in each row. 12 of those are from `line_items`. And at the end of the second foreach loop, there is `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);` And this works fine. Need help to solve the logic where I should locate the if statement or another foreach loop so I could make new rows each time when there is more than one `line_items` array under current `number`.

Comment: You talk about inserting into a Database. Please add the code where you try to do that.

Comment: @colburton `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);` and in `$stmt` is normal connection information to my database. With INSERT INTO of course. The data is inserting in the database like a charm. Only thing where I need the help is to solve the logic how I could insert only `number` and additional `line_items` when there is more than one `line_items` array. At the moment it insert the data correctly in the database, but if there would be more than one `line_items` array, it should make another database ROW and insert there only the `number` and the additionals `line_items`.

Comment: Well the answer will most likely involve foreach ($line['line_items'] ...), but unless you provide how your INSERT statement is created, we cannot help you.

Comment: @colburton INSERT statement is edited in.

Comment: @colburton Do you have any suggestions where I should involve foreach loop so the script would insert the first row as it do now and another rows for each additional `line_items` ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided JSON string I assume this code solves your problem:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents(JSON_URL), true);
foreach ($json['orders'] as $line) {
    foreach ($line['line_items'] as $item) {
        // no need to distinguish between 1 or more items
        // foreach handles both cases
        $number              = $line['number'];
        $line_item_id        = $item['id'];
        $line_item_sub       = $item['sub'];
        $line_item_sub_tax   = $item['sub_tax'];
        $line_item_total     = $item['total'];
        $line_item_total_tax = $item['total_tax'];
        $line_item_quantity  = $item['quantity'];
        $line_item_tax_class = $item['tax_class'];

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'isssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss', $number, $line_item_id, $line_item_sub, ...);
    }
}
```